# MATLAB R2017b. NARX neural networks - the numbers of input signals and networks inputs do not match

Tags: matlab, neural-network, modeling, recurrent-neural-network

Im trying to make some basic NARX Neural Network - just SISO. I am using MATLAB R2017b and Neural Networks Toolbox. The thing is that I need no delays at input and delays at feedback, so I can't use built-in app.

I created a net by using:

```
net1 = narxnet(0, 1, 5, 'open', 'trainbr');
```

The net was successfully created, and I can use view method to see it:
[Preview of my narxnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2X86.png)

How you can certainly see it has 0 inputs and 0 outputs yet, so I am trying to configure it, by using:

```
net1 = configure(net1, learnInput, learnOutput);
```

Where learnInput and learnOutput are 217x1 column vectors (even sized). This method fails and I get:

```
configure The numbers of input signals and networks inputs do not match.
```

Can anyone point me what I am doing bad and explain how to configure NARX correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for closedloop mode of network. I don't know why but it solved the problem.